# Accessing Webservice behind corporate proxy from Java client running within docker container

Tags: java, docker, proxy

I have a java web application running within a docker container.
From this web application I want to call a webservice which is behind a corporate proxy.

I am using Spring RestTemplate to call the web service.

I have tried few things.

1. Added proxy setting to docker client & also to the container.
   [Configure Docker to use a proxy](https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/)

With this I could login to the docker container.

```
docker exec -it myContainer bash
```

And execute curl to the intended webservice, which is working fine.

But when I am trying to invoke the same webservice from my Java code, then I am not able to connect.

2. I programatically tried to set the proxy in Java

> ```
> System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "myproxyhost");
> System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
> ```

But I could not connect from Java code.

Can you please help me here ?

Comment: And what error or response do you get when you try to make the http call with your java client? Please add the stack trace as well.

Comment: No Error is being returned, the request goes on forever and times out